# Is there a way to put Netbeans open files tab bar into several rows?

Tags: tabs, netbeans

Is there a way to put Netbeans open files tab bar into several rows? I have to scroll left and right when I open more than 3-4 files. For Firefox there is that extension "Tab Mix Plus" that provides that option. Is there a plugin or setting for this in Netbeans?

Comment: There used to be such tab bar in NetBeans 3 but it was removed. [Go vote](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=172512) and maybe they will bring it back. Until then you just have to downgrade or get used pressing Shift+F4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**NetBeans 8.0.2**

Tools > Options > Appearance > Document Tabs > Multi-row tabs

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Now such a feature exists since v7.2.

[image]